# Kill path file not found

Tags: excel, vba, kill

I am trying to delete all files in the below folder. However error comes up as

> run time error 75: path/file not found

However a couple of things to note:

1. It does delete some files, but the same ones it never deletes
2. The path does exist

Code:

```
Sub deleteprevfixing()
    'First delete file contents
    Dim aFile As String
    aFile = "R:\samsfiles\sam\!test\*.*"

    If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
         Kill aFile
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the correct rights to delete the files?

Comment: Hi @VincentG, yeah I have full rights, as its on a shared drive, it does ask if _'Are you sure you want to delete this file?'_ take a while saying _'preparing to recycle'_.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Tested on a shared drive it deletes everything in the given folder without asking. • This code should work as intended.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Do you think the question is forcing the error? Is there any way to suppress this?

Comment: @SamHarper Actually I don't know why you get the question at all. I just tested your code on Windows 10 Office 2016 with a shared drive on a server and it deletes without asking as intended. I don't use any special preferences almost everything is default in this test. • I just can say this is probably not a coding error. This must be something related to your Windows or folder privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted - thanks to all. It was because I had to turn off the "Are you sure you want to permanently delete this file?" dialog when deleting from a network share or mapped drive.

Here is a solution how to do it (copied from source below)

1. Map a network drive to the network share you want to use. Make sure
   that the drive is re-connected on logon.
2. Browse to `C:\users\<username>`.
3. Right-click on one of the folders in this location (any
   folder such as "links") and click properties.
4. Select the Location tab.
5. Click Move, browse to root of the drive you mapped in step 1,
   and click Select Folder.
6. Click Ok and click yes in the dialogue box
   that appears.

[Please see attached for original thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5645c0be-b42c-4aa3-bfd1-67282e117641/turn-off-permanently-delete-file-confirmation-dialog-on-mapped-drive)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all files in the folder (as your question suggests you want to), you need to keep looping and calling `dir()`. Otherwise, you will only delete the first file returned by `dir()`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteAllFilesInFolder()

    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "R:\samsfiles\sam\!test\"

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = VBA.FileSystem.Dir$(folderPath & "*.*", vbNormal) ' The "*.*" here isn't really necessary, but I'll leave it as is.

    Do Until Len(Filename) = 0
        Kill folderPath & Filename
        Filename = VBA.FileSystem.Dir$()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, great job almost, it now kicks off at the `Kill folderPath & Filename`. However it finds the correct filename as the next one in the list comes up when hovering over `Filename`